# Generics in PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint, generics, powershell

I need to use the SharePoint API in the following way in a PowerShell script:

### C# Code:

```
var service = farm.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>();
```

How does one specify the generics parameter in PowerShell?

At the moment I get an Exception stating that "Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenereicParameters is true"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not something you can easily do. You will have to resort to Reflection to make that work. See [this blog post](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/InvokingGenericMethodsOnNonGenericClassesInPowerShell.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was able to come up with the following solution:

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")

$farm = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm]::Local

$method = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPServiceCollection].GetMethod("GetValue", [string])
$closedmethod = $method.MakeGenericMethod([Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService])
$service = $closedmethod.Invoke($farm.Services, "")